# How to validate Hierarchical Select when adding new terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is there a way to validate [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) when adding new terms in sub level.

As for now the module is allowing new terms to add but there is no validation such as if I add a new term which is already existed, throw an error saying that "**Term name already existed**".

Is there any hook available when adding a new term so that we can validate before saving new term.

PS: I even had tried [Taxonomy Dupe](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_dupecheck) check, it doesn't support to [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).